# JavaScript function to validate an integer value

Tags: javascript

I'm building a shopping cart and I would like to use a JavaScript function to validate user input when entering the quantity value in the quantity text input. I would like to allow the entering of integer values only (no floats, no other characters).

I know that I can apply this function using onKeyUp event and also I found isNaN() function, but it returns true even for floats (which is not ok).

Can you guys help me out with this one?

Thanks.

Comment: there is a nice jQuery plugin for this: http://digitalbush.com/projects/masked-input-plugin/

Comment: Don't forget to validate on the server side, too. It's very easy to stop JavaScript outputting 'irritating' messages like “Hey you! You're supposed to only input *numbers* here!”.

Comment: @meo, pretty nice indeed. Thanks.

Answer (score 6):

You can always check with parseInt:

```
if (number == parseInt(number))
```

Comment: OR'ing a value with 0 is faster: `if (number == (number | 0))`.

Comment: BEWARE: both answers above will return true for the strings '0x10' and '10.000000', '00000', '-0', and '+0'. Virtually always parseInt should be passed 10 as the second parameter to force it to use base 10 ie. `parseInt(number,10)`. |0 is probably no faster if passed a string.

Comment: BEWARE: also the string '0e-400' returns true for both given solutions... and there are probably other corner cases (maybe near +/-MaxInt). Validating integers is hard in Javascript :)